# Laravel - LIKE operator to search for encrypted values

Tags: php, sql, laravel, encryption, sql-like

I am trying to implement a search module in my Laravel app that could filter users by name. In order to protect users, the `'name'` column rows are encrypted on DB. The problem that I am facing is that query below always returns 0 results.

I am encrypting the search input value before searching into DB.

```
$patients = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE name LIKE '%".Crypt::encrypt($searchText)."%';"));
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Because of your encryption, you cannot simply search. Now you encrypt a new name, but this is not a part of the encrypted name (otherwise the encryption would be flawed).

Comment: you have to decrypt your username in your program logic and do a contains

Answer (score 1):

```
Crypt::encrypt("Text")
```

The above will rarely generate the same value each time you call it, therefore you will not have the same value stored in your DB.

**Suggestion**

Don't encrypt users names unless you really have to. If you do have to encrypt the names then try the following.

```
$patients = DB::select("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE name = '".Crypt::encrypt($searchText)."'");
```

Your encrypted value will be case sensitive so change the column collation to `latin1_general_cs`

Comment: also you can't search for part of an encrypted text, LIKE and encrypt can never work together or something is seriously wrong with your encryption

Comment: Edited my answer to include suggestion.

Comment: this still doesn't answer the question though tbh, because the OP wanted to know how to search his table with LIKE, this only allows the user to find the exact name, but as I said, LIKE and encrypt will never work with pure sql so I guess this is as close as anyone can get

Comment: "Rarely" should be equivalent to *never* if encryption is done right and the random number generator is good.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but yes, this doesn't answer my first question. So I guess I can't search through my table. Working on a medical app, patient names have to be encrypted :/

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong here ?

Laravel's encryption is properly implemented, which means that each message is [randomized](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/70059609995/crypto-noobs-1-initialization-vectors)!

Randomization introduces a challenge for implementing searchable encryption: You never get the same ciphertext twice. Fortunately, there's a [workaround for making encryption searchable](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql).

1. Encrypt each record using [authenticated encryption](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken).
2. Separately, store HMAC-SHA2/BLAKE2 of the plaintext (with a separate key than the encryption key). You may truncate the hash function output. This is called a **blind index**.

   - Additionally, you may store multiple hash functions of various slices or transformations of the plaintext. (e.g. last 4 digits, first initial + last name, etc.)
   - Each blind index should have a distinct key.
   - You can combine multiple fields into a single blind index.
   - For low-entropy inputs (e.g. boolean fields), [never use them in isolation](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet/blob/v2.0.0/docs/solutions/01-boolean.md).
   - You may also use a slow KDF function (PBKDF2, Argon2id) for highly sensitive fields, although this is not strictly necessary.
3. Recalculate the blind indexes when doing SELECT queries, rather than trying to select based on the ciphertext itself.

This may sound like a lot, but in practice, [CipherSweet](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet) implements all the low-level machinery and should be easy enough for most PHP developers to use. (If this turns out to not be the case, file a bug on Github; we want it to be the case!)