# Can i search encrypted data in Laravel

Tags: laravel-encryption

In the Laravel, I have encrypted records in my table and I would like to search these records.

The problem occur when I do search and encrypt again my search term, it encrypts it again generating random string.

Comment: why are you querying encrypted data? It sounds like the encryption is working the way it is supposed to

Comment: There are many search results about this. Did you try searching first? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575601/laravel-like-operator-to-search-for-encrypted-values / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912168/laravel-with-datatables-searching-encrypted-data / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765561/laravel-how-to-search-for-specific-field-that-is-encrypted